# Python, Anaconda, pybrain on a Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, pybrain

I installed anaconda, but I'm also using pip:

```
$ conda list scipy
# packages in environment at /Users/bjelline/anaconda:
#
scipy                     0.14.0               np19py27_0  
$ conda list pybrain
# packages in environment at /Users/bjelline/anaconda:
#
pybrain                   0.3                       <pip>
```

These two are supposed to work together, aren't they?
when I do

```
/Users/bjelline/anaconda/bin/python -c "import pybrain"
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/bjelline/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from structure.__init__ import *
  File "/Users/bjelline/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/structure/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from connections.__init__ import *
  File "/Users/bjelline/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/structure/connections/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from full import FullConnection
  File "/Users/bjelline/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/structure/connections/full.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scipy import reshape, dot, outer
ImportError: cannot import name reshape
```

any thoughts what the problem might be?

Comment: Make sure it isn't picking up any other Python via the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or the `~/.local` directory.

Comment: PYTHONPATH is unset, no python in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Not /usr/local, ~/.local. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about ~/.local!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem wasn't anaconda, or python, or pip.  The problem were files called

```
pybrain.py
```

and

```
scipy.py
```

in the current directory.  the current directory is first in sys.path, so these files got loaded instead of the real libraries.

Note to self: never reuse a packages name as your own filename!

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda install -f scipy`.  This will force reinstall scipy.